# How can I copy a Docker container's configuration when I commit an image?

Tags: docker, commit, linux-containers

Ideally everything will be sorted out with a Dockerfile and volumes, but sometimes that isn't practical or convenient.

For example, I found an image with Ghost already set up, and it seemed to work.  So I added a few blog entries.  Then I realized that I actually needed to modify the config.js to set up the mail.

So I stopped the container, committed, made some changes in bash, committed again, and then went to go start the container again running Ghost.  But I had trouble getting it to work because the new image didn't have the configuration with the working directory and environment.

How can I copy the Docker container's configuration when I commit an image?  Maybe I need to write a script that runs `docker inspect` on the container, pulls the config out, and then includes that in the `docker commit` command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1141

The way you describe is still the best to achieve that I think, but I'd try using `docker insert` and see if that yield better results.